# Find aggregate root usages across the domain

Tags: domain-driven-design

As a matter of fact, *Entities* and even *Value Objects* may contain references to *Aggregate Roots*.
Additionally as per definition, *Aggregate Roots* stand on their own, the have intrinsically a *Repository* where I not at last could delete that *Aggregate Root*.

As a requirement of my GUI / Workflow, the customer wants to see where a particular Aggregate Root is referenced, not least because he wants / should be able to check whether he can delete that AR "safely".

My current design only has the navigation from the Entity in question *towards* the other AggregateRoot, so there's, at the moment, no simple way to find the opposite direction.

As this is surely not a single case, I wonder how this is done usually?

**Addendum:**

Consider the following example; we have an `Address` as *Entity*, and a *Value Object* `HomeVisit` containing `date` and `Address address` (just for the simplicity).
Until now, there is no modelling need to be able to navigate from `Address` to `HomeVisit`, even more since bidirectional associations are discouraged in general.
But you should see the use case now: For any reason I might need to be able to find out where an `Address` is currently used prior to delete or even modify it (maybe a service technician is currently on its way to that address and I need to be aware of that).

You can argue that for these cases there must be a *Service* or similar to find that out, but imagine there's a third party module which brings the `HomeVisit` *VO* and makes use of the `Address` somehow anonymously; at least that's the way I would like it to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the answer is: via Domain or Application Services, involving respective Repositories whereas necessary.

So, the check for references has to be kinda hard-coded with an AddressService, having a method like `deleteAddressByIdentifier`. This method then needs to check or invoke a method `isTechnicianOnWayToAddress()` which again queries Repositories accordingly; or whatever is needed to fulfil the goal.